# What does 'pro rata' mean in an agreement?

Tags: fees, services, agreement

I will make an agreement with a company and the text of the agreement includes the following sentence:

> Remote Based
> Fee USD **$1,200** per month (pro rata) during the period of 1st May 2022 and 31st July 2022.

Does it mean "**$1,200** x 3 month = $3,600" or "$400 x 3 month = **$1,200**"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's $1200 per month. The 'pro rata' means if you work less than one month, you still get compensated - so e.g. if you work only 2.5 months then you are paid $1200 x 2.5 = $3000.

Answer (score 5):

*Pro Rata* is the lawyer’s fancy way of saying ‘proportionally’.
It means that for incomplete months the amount gets proportionally adjusted, like 1/30 for one day, 2/30 for two days, etc.

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same as the answer that already existed.